# Как выделить целое слово не имея полный текст и удалить его на Python?

Tags: python, select

Допустим у меня есть текст "Телеграм юзер - `@usernamee`", мне нужно чтобы *Python* автоматически нашел и выделил целое слово которое начинается с символа **`@`** (в нашем случае это `@usernamee`) и удалил/заменил его.

Comment: Приведите код, который у вас есть. Иначе ничего конкретного сказать нельзя.

Comment: import re s = re.sub(r'@\w+', "Телеграм юзер - @usernamee")

Comment: Благодарю, это помогло!